# Whats the correct name for the filament driving mechanism used in 3d printer extruders and MIG wire feeders?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

Looking for the correct terminology to for the cable/filament feeding mechanism used in 3d printer filament feeder where the filament is gripped between a bearing and a gnarled gear tooth driven by motor - also seen in MIG-welder wire feeders. Would like to be able to do some searching to find out more on integrating similar mechanism to retract either stainless steel cable or Dyneema rope in something I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the term you seek is "hobbed gear." It's a cylinder typically attached to the extruder motor or drivetrain with a series of cuts about the circumference. A pressure roller is positioned parallel to the hobbed gear, or in the case of Bondtech drives, a second hobbed gear is located similarly and geared to the drive side.

[image: hobbed gear]